# Is there a word for telling someone all your thoughts?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for telling someone all your thoughts? For example, when you've been trying not to talk about something but you end up blurting it all out in one big mess of emotion and it's all over the place and almost desperate. Or just a word that describes someone desperately yelling all their thoughts to no one in particular; they are just getting their thoughts out.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts. This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Single word requests as yours are required to provide an example sentence about the way the word will be used.

Comment: Well, a single word doesn't do it justice so I just have to tell you that it really burns me when someone gets started talking and just runs on and on and on about some topic that you weren't really interested about in the first place but acted like you were just to be polite but now you're trapped and you're hoping that they will run out of characters in the comment before you die of boredom but it seems like they're just going to keep on going forever and you're starting to get hungry and you really need to pee and if they don't quit soon you're just going to punch them in the nose and tell

Comment: We have something you'd translate like `sinceriside` in Spanish - a mashup between `sincere` and `suicide` that works pretty OK in English, too.

Comment: Sounds a bit like “_emotionally incontinent_” in lay usage.

Comment: I read the question's title and thought "mind meld" ....but then I read the rest of the question, and I stopped thinking "mind meld." And then I unpaused my youtube video of fluffy cats doing group theory, or w/e it was.

Comment: Please add a sample sentence to your question with a blank for the word.

Comment: @Helmar required by who? If this is a site rule it doesn't seem to have been enforced here. The question is still open and has been protected by a moderator.

Comment: @HotLicks that's especially true when you're waiting for their sentence to end to interject your apology that you must retire, only to discover that  the sentence has no end. Have you noticed, incidentally, that the subject of such one-way conversations usual concerns the speaker's recent activities and achievements?

Comment: @MartinSmith sometimes the rules are overwhelmed by events. Anyhow the protection is not because it's a good question. It's to avoid low quality spam. That kind of spam is mostly attracted by unclear questions.

Comment: @Helmar the point about protection was just that it shows a moderator had clearly seen the question but opted not to close it.

Answer (score 41):

It's definitely "colloquial", but from [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unload)...

> **unload** - *to tell someone about your problems, the things that worry you, etc.*
>    (e.g. - I've been unloading my worries on poor Ann here)

---

The example usage *unloading my worries* above clearly shows how this particular metaphoric usage came about in the first place, but almost 2000 written instances of [unload on you](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22unload%20on%20you%22) in Google Books should be sufficient to show that the *intransitive* usage is well established.

Comment: Or sometimes more specifically, *to unload your feelings*. As in your example: *unloading my worries*. I'd say that it is transitive rather than intransitive, you wouldn't say *I'm unloading* there's always something that you're unloading.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: I kinda wish I hadn't included that example now! :) The whole *point* of my post was to show that in recent decades (unqualified) ***unload*** has come to be understood as *specifically* meaning *dump your emotional hangups on someone else.* As in [Sometimes you just need to unload.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Sometimes+you+just+need+to+unload%22)

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is that your point is correct (and I have up-voted it) it might want qualifying with the fact that it is usually accompanied by 'feelings', 'worries' &c

Comment: Your edit is spot on, thanks for building upon both of our points.

Answer (score 40):

How about **vent**?

From Dictionary.com:

> **vent**: to give free play or expression to (an emotion, passion, etc.): 
>   *to vent rage*; to give public utterance to: *to vent one's opinions*; to relieve by giving expression to something: *He vented his
>   disappointment by criticizing his successor.*

From the OP's example:

> *"When you've been trying not to talk about something but you end up blurting it all out in one big mess of emotion and it's all over the
>   place and almost desperate,"* you are **venting** your *pent-up* emotions, confusion, anger, frustration ... or you are simply **venting**.

Comment: I would add 'rant' to this post, since I feel like venting might not cover the situation of emptying your thoughts to no one in particular. I've always thought of venting as something that required an audience.

Answer (score 34):

The closest British English match (for this particularly emotional example) is

> "To pour your heart out."

Comment: This has mostly positive connotations - to tell all the thoughts and feelings that are troubling you to a sympathetic listener.

Answer (score 31):

It isn't a single word, but consider the idiom "spill ones guts," as shown in [Idioms by The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spill+guts):

> to tell all; to confess;
>
> to tell secret or personal information
>
> to tell someone all about yourself, especially your problems

You don't currently give an example sentence, but based on your description here is how it might be used:

> *After all of Bob's badgering her over her recent hesitance to talk, Alice was ultimately compelled to **spill her guts**.*

Comment: "To let it all out" is another idiom with the same meaning.

Comment: "To get it off his chest" might also cover the OP. "I just got it off my chest and blurted out my disappointment at the way she had treated me". To express something that has been worrying you and that you have wanted to say. (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: @PeterPoint *Getting it off one's chest* suggests to me something in the nature of a confession of guilt, which I'm not sure was what the OP was wanting.

Comment: "spill ones guts" has more negative connotations - the implication is that you've been forced to tell when you'd rather not. It is also usually used for the act of imparting information, rather than thoughts or emotions.

Answer (score 17):

Its not a single word, but how about "[brain dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_dump)"? The most common sense means explaining or writing down everything you know about a subject. It is generally used to refer to knowledge rather than emotion though.

Comment: My first thought when I read the title. Agreed on the caveat, though.

Comment: The caveat leads me to consider *heart dump*.

Comment: Dammit you beat me... By 11 hours! This was exactly my first thought even when it comes to emotion.

Comment: This *can* be a single word.  In fact, [according to ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=braindump%2Cbrain+dump&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbraindump%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbrain%20dump%3B%2Cc0), "braindump" is now more common than "brain dump".

Answer (score 15):

To "bare one's soul" to someone would seem to cover the OP's situation although it's not one word.

He felt a great sense of relief after being asked by his doctor to **bare his soul** about his innermost worries and anxieties.

To bare one's soul: reveal one's innermost secrets and feelings to someone. (Google online).

Comment: @Runic-Scribe  Suggested edit "bear" [sic] to bare acknowledged.

Comment: Please add a reference link. Else, this is a good one.

Comment: @alwayslearning  I was merely acknowledging Runic-Scibe's edit which corrected my misspelling of the word "bare" which I had written as "bear" [sic] in my original OP. A Freudian slip on my part, I think. My nickname is Bear! Have I referenced the link adequately?

Comment: Well, my earlier comment was just asking the answerer (you!) to add a (_clickable_) link to their reference.

Answer (score 10):

Confide:  *verb*

1   reveal in private; tell confidentially;

2   confer a trust upon; to show confidence by imparting secrets.

Comment: This is a good answer. I would have upvoted if you gave a citation/reference.

Comment: This is the correct meaning of 'Confide', but that's not a word that means 'telling someone all your thoughts' i.e what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking all thoughts, as they occur?

Not a single word, but how about *Stream of consciousness*, referring to the verbal narrative mode (rather than the actual awareness 'streaming' through your head.)

Another might be: *full disclosure*.   Imagine two people watching a ranting lunatic across the street who yells out every thought as it occurs.  They look at each other, and the first one says "Full disclosure?"  The second smiles and says "TMI!"

:)

Answer (score 2):

***lay bare*** one's soul

M-W Learner's Dictionary:

> [***bare***](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/bare)  *adjective*
>
> 1  a : not having a covering
>
> — sometimes used figuratively
>
> He ***laid bare*** his soul. = He laid his soul bare. [=he revealed his most
>   private thoughts and feelings]

Answer (score 1):

To be **candid**, to say what you really think without glossing over or leaving out parts that may be distasteful.

Comment: Hi, user195091, and thanks for your contribution to English Language & Usage. I think your suggested word is an excellent one, but you could make it more definitive by quoting a suitable a definition in a good dictionary and citing your source in your answer. I would gladly upvote your answer if you added such corroborating support to it.

Comment: Don't be so hasty - candid that is the correct definition of candid, but that's not the meaning that the OP was looking for

Answer (score 1):

If someone has been keeping something to themselves for a long time it can cause them a lot of stress. A friend might then come alongside them, see that they need to divulge their private thoughts, and suggest it might do them good to 'offload'.

'**Offload**: Relieve oneself of (a problem or worry) by talking to someone else'

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/offload

Another, closely-related word would be

**Unburden oneself**: Relieve (someone) of something that is causing them anxiety or distress: 'the need to unburden yourself to someone who will listen'

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unburden

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the phase *verbal diarrhea*.  It has some strong connotations to both desperation and a "big mess of emotion" like in the question.

> **verbal diarrhea**
>
> NOUN, *vulgar slang*
>
> **The fact or habit of talking too much**:
>
> > *'was it necessary to have the narrator exhibit verbal diarrhea throughout the entire picture?'*
>
> <sub>Source: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/verbal-diarrhea</sub>

Comment: _logorrhea_ means the same, without the icky metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

**Gush**

1. to issue copiously or violently
2. to make an effusive display of affection or enthusiasm

*Example:* I'm tired of hearing her gush about her boyfriend.

[M-W.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gush)
I removed the inapplicable definition

Answer (score 0):

You are [ranting](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20rant):

> **verb**
>
> speak or shout at length in a wild, impassioned way.
>
> *"she was still ranting on about the unfairness of it all"*
>
> **synonyms:** fulminate, go on, hold forth, vociferate, sound off, spout, pontificate, bluster, declaim; shout, yell, bellow; informal:
>   mouth off
>
> "she ranted about the unfairness"
>
> **noun**
>
> a spell of ranting; a tirade.
>
> *"his rants against organized religion"*
>
> **synonyms:** tirade, diatribe, broadside; literaryphilippic
>
> *"he went into a rant about them"*

Answer (score 0):

**Open up [to someone]**

Definition:

> To start to talk more about yourself and your feelings.

Use in a sentence:

> I've never opened up to anyone like I do to you.

Source: [Cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/open-up)

Answer (score 0):

Unload, venting, and especially ranting have the connotation that the information is negative and/or the person giving it is exaggerating the impact.

"get this/something off my chest" or "blurt out" give the feeling that the speaker has been holding back on something serious and has finally said it while leaving it ambiguous if the thing is positive or negative.

For example:

He said, "I've got to get this off my chest.  I've been offered a promotion, but we'll have to move to another city."

At Dinner, he blurted out the news of his promotion.

Answer (score 0):

One of the idiomatic uses of "dump" has a meaning like this.
From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dump):

> 24. dump on (someone), Informal.
>
>     b) to unload one's problems onto (another person):
>
>     *You never phone me without dumping on me.*

From [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dump+on):

> dump something on someone
>
> Fig. to pour out one's troubles to someone. *She dumped all her grief on her friend, Sally. I wish you wouldn't dump all your problems on me.*

The advantage of these idioms for your intended use is that several of the ordinary meanings of "to dump" ("to drop or let fall in a mass", "to unload or empty out [...], as by tilting or overturning", "to transfer or rid oneself of suddenly and irresponsibly", again from Dictionary.com) are suggestive of the act of suddenly and messily blurting out many emotional thoughts.

The disadvantage of the first idiom is that the other idiomatic meaning of "to dump on someone," which I think is more commonly recognized, is to criticize someone, and the disadvantage of the second idiom is that "to dump something on someone" often means to suddenly give someone an undesirable task to perform. In order to avoid those connotations
you would have to be careful about context and framing. (On the other hand, if those connotations are consistent with the act of blurting out the things in question, you might not need to try so hard to avoid them.)

Answer (score -1):

I think the person who does this is *dysinhibited*, and when he does this, he is showing *dysinhibition*.  Another way to say this is "leaky brakes".

Here's an old-fashioned expression to fit with your first example: You *wear your heart on your sleeve.*

Comment: While these are similar concepts, "wearing your heart on your sleeve" is a continuous state, much like "friendly" or "vicious".  The act of unloading or getting it off your chest is not described by "wearning your heart on your sleeve".

Answer (score -1):

Vent is pretty good, but how about [divulge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divulge)?

> 2
>   :  to make known (as a confidence or secret)

It means exactly what you want, but it has the added advantage of being something like an onomatopoeia, bringing up mental imagery of a dam breaking, and info flooding out.

Comment: Again, this is the correct meaning of 'divulge', but that's not what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest indiscreet:

> adj. having, showing, or proceeding from too great a readiness to reveal  things that should remain secret or private.
>
> "they have been embarrassed by indiscreet friends"