# How to apologize for bringing in many issues at once?

Tags: phrase-requests

Let's assume I have a one-on-one with my boss and I start bringing up the many issues that could be improved in the organization. How do I tone my criticism down a bit?

Something like:
"Sorry for [machine gunning] issues, but could we also buy a coffee machine that makes stronger coffee?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the idiom *piling it on*: "Sorry for *piling it on like this*, but could we..."

[The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/piling+it+on) defines *piling it on* as "To continue to add to something until the amount or effect becomes excessive".

You could also say, "Sorry for *piling all these issues onto you*, but could we..."

[The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pile+on) defines *piling onto* in this context as "To load many people or things on(to) someone or something all at once or in a heap."

You could also try "Sorry for *dumping all these issues on you*, but could we..."

[The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dump+on+(someone+or+something)) defines *dumping on* in this context as "pouring out one's troubles to someone."

If you wanted to stick closely to your machine-gun image, you could say, "Sorry for the *rapid-fire* issues, but could we..."

I found a similar use of the word *rapid-fire* in the [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/rapid-fire).

The alternative with *dumping* is perhaps a bit less elegant than those with *piling* or *rapid-fire*. As someone who worked in the corporate world for 25 years, my personal preference would be the simple *piling it on*, but that is, of course, just opinion.

FYI, in checking for duplicates, I found [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347104/is-there-a-word-for-telling-someone-all-your-thoughts/347714#347714) on ELU, but I think it deals with a different context, one where someone is involved in an emotional situation, rather than a business discussion.